Reading event-ID from the struct _EVT_SYSTEM_PROPERTY_ID gives incorrect data?
Trying to print the event ID using WIN32 API gives incorrect data (compared the output result with the event viewer).
Event rendering part
hContext = EvtCreateRenderContext(0, NULL, EvtRenderContextUser);
if (NULL == hContext)
{
    ERRMSG("ParseEventDataBySource: Failed with error code : %lu\n", errorCode = GetLastError());
    goto cleanup;
}

if (!EvtRender(hContext, hEvent, EvtRenderEventValues, dwBufferSize, pRenderedValues, &dwBufferUsed, &dwPropertyCount))
{
    if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == (errorCode = GetLastError()))
    {
        dwBufferSize = dwBufferUsed;
        pRenderedValues = (PEVT_VARIANT)malloc(dwBufferSize);
        if (pRenderedValues)
        {
            EvtRender(hContext, hEvent, EvtRenderEventValues, dwBufferSize, pRenderedValues, &dwBufferUsed, &dwPropertyCount);

My Code to fetch the event ID
UINT16 EventID;
EventID = pRenderedValues[EvtSystemEventID].UInt16Val;
eventIDString.Format(" [EventID : %hu] ", EventID);
dataBuffer += eventIDString; 

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/rendering-events
The code from reference
   DWORD EventID = pRenderedValues[EvtSystemEventID].UInt16Val;
    if (EvtVarTypeNull != pRenderedValues[EvtSystemQualifiers].Type)
    {
        EventID = MAKELONG(pRenderedValues[EvtSystemEventID].UInt16Val, pRenderedValues[EvtSystemQualifiers].UInt16Val);
    }
    wprintf(L"EventID: %lu\n", EventID);

How do I print event ID.

Could you please provide a minimum sample to help us reproduce the issue? How do you print the event ID. And  how did you determine that reading the event ID from _EVT_SYSTEM_PROPERTY_ID was incorrect?

Updated the question

You are using the EvtRenderContextUser flag. EVT_SYSTEM_PROPERTY_ID enumeration defines the identifiers that identify the system-specific properties of an event. If you want to use EVT_SYSTEM_PROPERTY_ID to print event ID, you need to use EvtRenderContextSystem instead of EvtRenderContextUser.
Refer to the Doc:EVT_RENDER_CONTEXT_FLAGS enumeration
